# Delaying the firing of Lightswitch autocomplete filters

Tags: c#, autocomplete, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to find a way to delay the list retrieval on a **Lightswitch autocomplete box** so that it only fires after 3 characters have been entered by the user.

This is for performance reasons so that LS doesn't return thousands of items after the first character is entered which delays user input.

Once 3 characters have been entered I want the autocomplete list to retrieve items where xxx LIKE 'abc%' rather than where xxx LIKE 'a%' which is the default behaviour. Is there anyway of specifying a minimum number of characters to be entered before the the Autocomplete works ?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this example can be ported over to light switch, but the easiest way to do this sort of thing is using Reative Extensions.  This blog post goes through the details. [EXAMPLE](http://blog.petegoo.com/index.php/2011/11/22/building-an-auto-complete-control-with-reactive-extensions-rx/)

Apologizes if this is does not work, i've only used these extensions in wpf.